# Making a socks proxy using PHP

Tags: php, proxy, webserver

Using ssh, I can use another computer as a proxy, for ex.

```
$ssh -D 9999 username@ip-address-of-ssh-server
```

Now, I can configure my application to use socks proxy on port 9999 at the above given up address.

If I own a web server, can i make a php script which also listens from connections on a particular port (preferably access provided through **password**)?

Comment: It's probably possible somehow, but why use a slow, interpreted language to pass through streams of data?

Comment: Because i have a blocked connection & so i want to use it as a proxy. Sadly, i dont have ssh access to the web server.

Comment: Is it "only" php-enabled webspace? Then the answer is probably "no" since php will only run as long as a http request is handled. You'd need something that runs all the time (in the background).

Comment: what if i just want a http proxy..?

Comment: If you mean a "real" proxy (maybe because you want to run something like corkscrew) you have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into projects like PHProxy? I can't really tell if that's what you're after, though.

Here's a link to the abovementioned: http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/

Comment: This is a client/server socket server that in fact does http connections using the php_socket. Lot of interesting.